# Every subgroup $H$ of $G$ with $H\ne G$ is cyclic. Is $G$ cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $(G,*)$ be a group. Suppose that every subgroup $H$ of $G$ with $H\ne  G$ is cyclic. Is $G$ cyclic? Justify your answer.

What i tried

I mentioned that $G$ is not necessarily cyclic. Using Lagrange theorem every subgroup of $G$ has an order which is the  divisor of the order of $G$. Say if the order of $G$ is $6$ then every subgroup must have an order of $1$, $2$, or $3$ for this case. And since all the subgroup are cyclic, then this implies that $G$ must have elements of order of $1$ , $2$ and $3$ but $G$ does not necessarily need to have an element of order $6$ which is the necessary condition for $G$ to be cyclic, since for $G$ to be cyclic the order of an element in $G$ need to be equal to the order of the group and this provide a counterexample. However i still could not think of a specific counterexample with this conditions, Could anyone help me with this. Thanks

Comment: What about the Klein four group?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, just look at $\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2$, the 3 subgroups are $\Bbb Z_2\times0$ and $0\times\Bbb Z_2$ and $\Bbb Z_2(1\times1)$, all of which are cyclic, but $\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2$ is not cyclic.

Comment: There's also the diagonal subgroup $\{(0,0),(1,1)\}$ (of course, still cyclic).

Comment: Thanks for teh addition, I forgot it, but you are correct :)

Answer (score 1):

This is false, another view on the already given example : If a group is of prime order (that is the number of elements in the group is a prime number) then it is cyclic.

Combine this with the Lagrange Therom that a subgroup order must divide the group order to see that if the order of a group is only divisible by prime numbers then every subgroup is cyclic (why?)

Now, we don't want our group to be cyclic, the smallest example would to come up with a group of order that is a multiple of two  primes , in the example given - 2 and two.

All this promised us that the subgroups would be cyclic, we do need to know a construction that would give us a non cyclic group - the Cartesian product does just that.

Note the comment to this answer, taking distinct primes won't yield the results we wish.

Comment: Actually the direct product _doesn't_ give you a non-cyclic group in this case -- when $p,q$ are different primes, $C_p\times C_q$ is isomorphic to $C_{pq}$ due to the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: @HenningMakholm right, thanks. I edited accordingly